# preg_match string from meta name

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to preg_match  number "20,956" from $url1 and number "2,894,865" from $url2

$url1:

```
<meta name="description" content="&#x200e;ST. Eye Clinic - &#x639;&#x64a;&#x627;&#x62f;&#x629; &#x62f;&#x643;&#x62a;&#x648;&#x631; &#x645;&#x62d;&#x645;&#x62f; &#x639;&#x632;&#x628; &#x644;&#x637;&#x628; &#x648; &#x62c;&#x631;&#x627;&#x62d;&#x629; &#x627;&#x644;&#x639;&#x64a;&#x648;&#x646;&#x200e;, Dumyat Al Jadidah, Dumyat, Egypt. 20,956 visits &#xb7;
```

$url2:

```
<meta name="description" content="ABC. 2,894,865 visits &#xb7;
```

Tried this to work for both of urls, it works for only $url1 but not in $url2

```
$p = preg_match("'Egypt. (.*?) visits'si", $url, $matches);
$p2 = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $matches[1]);      
print $p2;
```

Any Idea to make it work for both $url1&2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```php
if (preg_match('~\d[,\d]*(?=\s*visits)~', $url, $matches)) {
  echo $matches[0];
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JZ5otU/1). *Details*:

- `\d` - a digit
- `[,\d]*` - zero or more commas/digits
- `(?=\s*visits)` - a positive lookahead that requires zero or more whitespaces and then `visits` string immediately to the right of the current location.

See a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/bQC8m):

```php
$urls = ['<meta name="description" content="&#x200e;ST. Eye Clinic - &#x639;&#x64a;&#x627;&#x62f;&#x629; &#x62f;&#x643;&#x62a;&#x648;&#x631; &#x645;&#x62d;&#x645;&#x62f; &#x639;&#x632;&#x628; &#x644;&#x637;&#x628; &#x648; &#x62c;&#x631;&#x627;&#x62d;&#x629; &#x627;&#x644;&#x639;&#x64a;&#x648;&#x646;&#x200e;, Dumyat Al Jadidah, Dumyat, Egypt. 20,956 visits &#xb7;',
    '<meta name="description" content="ABC. 2,894,865 visits &#xb7;'];
foreach ($urls as $url) {
  if (preg_match('~\d[,\d]*(?=\s*visits)~', $url, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[0] . PHP_EOL;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
20,956
2,894,865
```